# How to discern this error message from React with out error boundaries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, error-handling

I received the error message below.  However I am using functional components and can not add error boundaries per the suggestion.

I see the call stack of components F1 -> F1Page -> A1Bookmark.  What does 28:66 represent?  Are one of these numbers the line number.

I'm using webpack for a development build, so the names are clearly visible, but I still need the line number.

```
The above error occurred in the <__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__> component:

    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack:///./A1Bookmark/A1Bookmark.jsx?:28:66)
    at div
    at div
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack:///./F1Page/F1Page.jsx?:27:70)
    at div
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack:///./F1/F1.jsx?:32:70)
    at Provider (webpack:///./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js?:16:3)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Comment: the `28` is the line number and the `16` is the column or the character in that line.

Comment: you can still add even class based error boundaries if you are generally use functional components. however, error boundaries probably won't help a lot. Error boundaries are less useful for debugging and won't display much more information, but they should avoid _unexpected_ errors, or errors outside of your control (i.e. in libraries), to crash the whole page.